# Group child nodes into group of 4

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XSLT, I am using identity transform because I need to keep the xml intact and only change a specific section of the XML i.e: the `<committee committeetype="Associate">`

```
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
        <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

        <!--Identity Transform.-->
        <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
          </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="committee[@committeetype='Associate']/affiliation">
            <Committee CommitteeType="Associate"> 
                <xsl:copy>  
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>   
                </xsl:copy>  
           </Committee >
      </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="committee[@committeeType='Associate']">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Transforms

```
<committee committeetype="Associate">
    <affiliation dbid="11">
        <name>Eve </name>
    </affiliation>
    <affiliation dbid="12">
        <name>Dan </name>
    </affiliation>
    <affiliation dbid="13">
        <name>Harold </name>
    </affiliation>
    <affiliation dbid="14">
        <name>Chris </name>
    </affiliation>      
    <affiliation dbid="25">
        <name>Malcolm </name>
    </affiliation>
    <affiliation dbid="15">
        <name>Mike </name>
    </affiliation>
</committee>
```

Into

```
            <committee committeetype="Associate">
                <affiliation dbid="11">
                    <name>Eve </name>
                </affiliation>
            </committee>
            <committee committeetype="Associate">
                <affiliation dbid="12">
                    <name>Dan </name>
                </affiliation>
            </committee>
            <committee committeetype="Associate">
                <affiliation dbid="13">
                    <name>Harold </name>
                </affiliation>
            </committee>
            <committee committeetype="Associate">
                <affiliation dbid="14">
                    <name>Chris </name>
                </affiliation>
            </committee>
            <committee committeetype="Associate">
                <affiliation dbid="25">
                    <name>Malcolm </name>
                </affiliation>
            </committee>
            <committee committeetype="Associate">
                <affiliation dbid="15">
                    <name>Mike </name>
                </affiliation>
            </committee>
```

> How can i make it so it groups the affiliation into 4 per `<committee committeetype="Associate">`

Such as

```
  <committee committeetype="Associate">
                <affiliation dbid="11">
                    <name>Eve </name>
                </affiliation>
                <affiliation dbid="12">
                    <name>Dan </name>
                </affiliation>
                <affiliation dbid="13">
                    <name>Harold </name>
                </affiliation>
                <affiliation dbid="14">
                    <name>Chris </name>
                </affiliation>
   </committee>
   <committee committeetype="Associate">
                <affiliation dbid="25">
                    <name>Malcolm </name>
                </affiliation>
               <affiliation dbid="15">
                    <name>Mike </name>
                </affiliation>
   </committeemembergroup>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a suggestion that might suffice:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:param name="chunk-size" select="4"/>

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

        <!--Identity Transform.-->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="committee[@committeetype='Associate']">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="affiliation[position() mod $chunk-size = 1]" mode="group"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="committee[@committeetype='Associate']/affiliation" mode="group">
    <committee committeetype="Associate">
      <xsl:apply-templates select=". | following-sibling::affiliation[position() &lt; $chunk-size]"/>
    </committee>
  </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It transforms

```
<committee committeetype="Associate">
    <affiliation dbid="11">
        <name>Eve </name>
    </affiliation>
    <affiliation dbid="12">
        <name>Dan </name>
    </affiliation>
    <affiliation dbid="13">
        <name>Harold </name>
    </affiliation>
    <affiliation dbid="14">
        <name>Chris </name>
    </affiliation>      
    <affiliation dbid="25">
        <name>Malcolm </name>
    </affiliation>
    <affiliation dbid="15">
        <name>Mike </name>
    </affiliation>
</committee>
```

into

```
<committee committeetype="Associate">
   <affiliation dbid="11">
      <name>Eve </name>
   </affiliation>
   <affiliation dbid="12">
      <name>Dan </name>
   </affiliation>
   <affiliation dbid="13">
      <name>Harold </name>
   </affiliation>
   <affiliation dbid="14">
      <name>Chris </name>
   </affiliation>
</committee>
<committee committeetype="Associate">
   <affiliation dbid="25">
      <name>Malcolm </name>
   </affiliation>
   <affiliation dbid="15">
      <name>Mike </name>
   </affiliation>
</committee>
```

I don't know however whether your `committee` elements have other child elements than the `affiliation` ones the above stylesheet processes. If there are more code is needed.